# How to load custom JS in Rails 7 ESBuild project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

I have `Rails 7.0.4`.

I generated the project using this command.

```
rails new myproject --database=postgresql -j esbuild --css bootstrap
```

Thus, I don't have a file named `config/importmap.rb`.

How do I load a single file with custom JS?

I tried creating a file with a single `console.log` here.

```js
// ./app/javascript/new.js

console.log('Hi')
```

and then load this file into the entry point `application.js` like this.

```js
// ./app/javascript/application.js

import "./new.js"
```

But I don't see any `console.log`.

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `esbuild` which means you have to compile/bundle your javascript. Rails gives a command to start the server and run *esbuild*:

```bash
bin/dev
```

This is somewhat glanced over in the readme, but it's there:  *https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails*

This should work just fine:

```
// app/javascript/application.js

import "./new"
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Even with a brand new rails project, `rails new jsexample -j esbuild` this doesn't work, the JS isn't loaded and I don't see a log to the screen. I did run the project using `bin/dev` as well.

Interestingly, I do see my custom JS inside of `./app/assets/builds/new.js` though, it just doesn't execute/log in the dev tools.

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran did you make a new controller? default rails page doesn't load the layout from your views. `bin/rails g controller home index` then go to `/home/index`.  you have to import `new.js` in `application.js` because thats what's in the layout `javascript_include_tag "application"`.

Comment: I did what you advised, created a new controller and page, and then checked there, as opposed to checking from the default home page. It worked, I saw the console.log in my chrome dev tools.

I ended up trying generating another rails project again to repeat and test the behavior and it worked a second time.

My original project still wouldn't load the files though.

I ended up copying over all of these files to the new install and then `rails db:reset` to get the js loaded. Strange.

./app/controllers/*
./app/helpers/*
./app/models/*
./app/views/*
./app/db/*
./Gemfile